# How to delete a user currently used by process?

Tags: linux-mint, users

I want to delete a user, with a 'Standard' account type and 'No password set'.

`userdel` returns:

```
userdel: user username is currently used by process 1239
```

Comment: You can't delete a user that is logged in or that has processes running by other means.

Comment: `ps -ef | awk '$2 == 1239'` will show you the relevant process detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete an user who has a running process, first you must kill that process. In your case:

```
kill -9 1239
```

If the user is logged in, that'll be their shell. Killing it will force the user to log out.

Then you can delete the user via

```
userdel username
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to do that on your own computer, I recommend you log in to a different [`tty`](https://www.howtogeek.com/428174/what-is-a-tty-on-linux-and-how-to-use-the-tty-command/) as `root` and delete the desired user from there. A `tty` is a teletype terminal, which simply executes commands.

Press `Ctrl + LAlt + F3` to log in to `tty3`.

Note that you can also use `F4`, `F5` and `F6` to access `tty4` to `tty6` respectively.  Note that using `F1` will return to the currently logged in user's login screen and `F2` would return you to the grphical user session you may have logged in to.

Now type `root` as the user, and the password for `root`.

Assuming the user you want to delete is `user1`, type `# userdel user1`
This method would leave behind the user's home directory and everything inside intact.

If you want to remove the home directory's contents and the user's mail spool as well, simply type

`# userdel -r user1`